# python 3, BeautifulSoup 4, scrape and print text of specific parse tree

Tags: python, parsing

I have searched around here and I haven't found a post yet that helps me in what I need to accomplish.

website: http://www.animefansftw.com/

I'm trying to get the h1 Title of all posts from a set date only!. I was able to get the actual posts for the set date but got stuck on how to get the h1 title of the posts.

```
import time
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Aniday = time.strftime("%B %d")
r = requests.get("http://www.animefansftw.com")  
r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
print("Today's Animu Crack:\n")

for div in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "date"}):
    get_date = div.text
    clean_date = " ".join(get_date.split())
    if clean_date == Aniday:
        print(clean_date)
```

Now to avoid confusion I can get the h1 title names for the posts just fine but i don't want all of them just those that contain the date I set.

```
for item in soup.find_all("h1"):
    info = item.text
    clean_info = " ".join(info.split())
    print(clean_info)
```

Comment: Is there a date element on the page maybe inside the div for the postings. If there is you could use some condition flow to loop through and only print the ones with the correct corresponding date elements. If there is no date elements on the post then I don't know how you would accomplish this unless there was some sort of timestamp in the html that the beautiful soup parser could extract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glancing at the source, it looks like the h1 tag is included in the parent's parent.

Try:

```
import time
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Aniday = time.strftime("%B %d")
r = requests.get("http://www.animefansftw.com")  
r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
print("Today's Animu Crack:\n")

for div in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "date"}):
    get_date = div.text
    clean_date = " ".join(get_date.split())
    if clean_date == Aniday:
        post_div = div.parent.parent
        title = post_div.h1.text.encode('ascii','ignore')
        print("{title}\n{date}\n".format(title=title,date=clean_date))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help & time. I'm still new to python and was wondering were i can read up on parent.

Comment: Navigating around the document is described in the Beautiful Soup documentation  The parent is mentioned in the "Going Up" section: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-up

Comment: Thank you, You have been a great help and I have learned so much managed to get the urls of the posts as well :) and a few other improvements
http://pastebin.com/vraUki4u